# Integer underflow/overflow

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, bug, overflow

What is integer overflow and underflow and how it can be possible? I saw its example that coders avoid this bug by `require(balanceOf(_to) +_value >= balanceOf(_to))`  where `_value` is an unsigned integer so it will always be positive and will add to the balance, so this is an understood thing so why is this condition needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidity does not have any built-in protection from over/underflow. This means that if you hit the min or the max of a value (`0` or `2^256-1 = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935`) then the value will "wrap" around and keep counting.

Put the following code in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) to test it out.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract FlowTest {

    uint256 public a = 0;
    uint256 public b = 2**256-1; 

    function flow () external {
        a -= 1;
        b += 1;
    }
}
```

If you deploy this contract, you will see that `a` and `b` are `0` and `2^256-1`, respectively. If you run `flow()`, you will see that they switch and `a = 2^256 - 1` and `b = 0`. This is because `a` *underflowed* and `b` _overflowed`.

If you run `flow()` once more, you will see that `a = 2^256-2` and `b = 1`.

OpenZeppelin's [`SafeMath.sol`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) is a widely used library that helps with this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and correcting the question, can you please elaborate what does wrap refer to here?

Comment: You can read more here https://javapapers.com/core-java/java-overflow-and-underflow/.

Imagine if you are trying to count to 11 on your fingers, you will not be able to because you have 10 fingers. Solidity is not smart enough to realize you only have 10 fingers, so when it adds 1 to your 10th "finger", it will start over at 1.